# Оптимизация Индексов для CDR

Tags: postgresql, index

Дано postgresql
Таблица 
"DATE" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
"DST-NUMBER" character varying(255)
"SRC-NUMBER" character varying(255)

Поиск обязательно по диапазону даты например 2016-12-11 по 2016-12-12
и одному из номеров например 7916%

размер 20GB 10мл записей

Посоветуйте какой индекс создать для ускорения запроса поиска?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А сколько записей за выбранный интервал дат ? И как именно заданы условия на интервал и как на номер

Comment: select * from cdr where "DATE" between '2016-12-13 00:00:00'::timestamp and '2016-12-13 23:59:59'::timestamp 
and  "DST-NUMBER" LIKE '7916%'

В сутки от 500000-1000000
Запрос можно переписать под индексы, главное скорость

Comment: попробуйте составной индекс `(date, dst-number)`

Comment: date("DATE"),"DST-NUMBER" 
а для 
date("DATE"),"SRC-NUMBER"
а если по обоим номерам искать
date("DATE"),"DST-NUMBER" ,  "SRC-NUMBER"
?

Comment: боюсь да, придется два индекса с dst и с src. не вижу особого смысла делать еще и по трем полям. по одному из двух существующих довольно быстро должно найти подходящее и из этого уже выберет по третьему полю

Comment: хотя конечно зависит от количества запросов на поиск по одному и по двум номерам. если по двум номерам часто и выборка день-8916% дает много записей можно сделать (date,src,dst) и (date,dst)

Comment: А если ещё партиции сделать по датам? Они же не меняются, значит каждая дата будет всегда сидеть в своей партиции и выборка будет не по всей базе, а только по партициям, попавшим в условие.

Comment: Партиции по месяцам сделаны в месяц размер 20GB 10мл записей

Comment: При postgre v.>= 9.2 я бы еще посоветовал добавить в индексы поля, выводимые запросом (если их не шибко много), даст прирост за счет only index scan.
И с партицированием по осторожнее, шибко много не делайте. У нас их настолко много, что только план запроса строится около 20 сек. Поэтому обращаемся либо к месячным таблицам, либо (в особо тяжелых случаях), используем хранимку, которая прогоняет данный ей запрос по таблицам соответсвующих дней и соответсвующих свичей. Прирост существенный даже в сравнении с месячной таблицей всех свичей (а у нее "всего лишь" ~300 наследований).

Comment: Индексировать поля которые не используются в выборке?

Comment: Поля, которые используются в выборке И выводе. Если индекс будет самодостаточен, то смотреть реальные значения в таблице никакой необходимости не будет и запрос ограничится лишь значениями индекса. Без сомнений, это быстрее, чем на каждую нужную запись смотреть в таблицу и брать дополнительные ее значения. Но все относительно, если выборка составляет пару десятков записей, то оно не стоит опухливания индекса.